# Parametrization of lines of steepest descent

Tags: differential-geometry

A circular pipe radius $a$ is inclined $\gamma$ to z-axis is parameterized

$$ (x,y,z)= ( a \cos u, a \sin u \cos\gamma + v \sin \gamma ,
 -a \sin u  \sin \gamma +  v \cos \gamma ) $$

( $u$ polar angle of pipe, length extrusion along  $v$ )

Rain drops falling on it when dust had settled on it already, leaving slide down trace marks à  Mongé concept for steepest descent paths.

Find $ v=f(u)$ single parameter steepest descent typical path parametrization of typical parallel tracks.

Comment: I think it would be better to let $v = h(u)$ instead of $u = f(v)$, because $u$ is an angle, and we want to avoid multi-valued inverse trig functions. Also, what is the purpose of $b$? It only occurs in the product $bv$, so we can change variables $bv \mapsto w$ .

Comment: Thanks, changed that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: TricklingRaindropsDownDirtyTube]

$v$ expression above (several $v_0$ values) taken from mr_e_man

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that the rain drops always take the steepest descent, ignoring the drops' inertia which may cause deviation from this path. And I'm setting $b = 1$ .

There's probably a better way to do this, but I solved for $v$ and $(\sin u)$ in terms of $x$ and $y$ to get
$$z = \frac{y \cos\gamma \pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2}}{\sin\gamma}$$
so the gradient is
$$\nabla z = \langle\frac{\partial z}{\partial x},\space \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\rangle = \langle\frac{-x}{\pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2}\sin\gamma},\space \frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}\rangle$$

We want $x$ and $y$ to move in this direction, so
$$x' = \frac{-x}{\pm\sqrt{a^2-x^2} \sin\gamma},\space y' = \frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}$$
where $x'$ means differentiation with respect to some unspecified parameter. Substituting back $u$ and $v$, and using the Chain Rule,
$$-a u'\sin u = \frac{-a\cos u}{-a\sin u \sin\gamma},\space a u'\cos u \cos\gamma + v'\sin\gamma = \frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma}$$

I rearranged these to solve for
$$\frac{dv}{du} = \frac{v'}{u'} = -a\frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma} \frac 1{\cos u}$$
$$v = -a\frac{\cos\gamma}{\sin\gamma} \tanh^{-1}(\sin u) + v_0$$
According to this equation, the drops go down and run along the bottom of the pipe, instead of falling off the side. In reality, they would fall off somewhere.

Comment: Visualization based on your last $v,$ is so convincing! The trace is along cylinder meridian at top/bottom asymptotically and at center tangents are strictly vertical.